# Quiero que persista mi base de datos sqlite en render.com

Tags: strapi

Im using this with .env on render

```
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=1337
APP_KEYS=yaXil0hnK1Shzy/ALIsgWA==,vjK1hxO2OHilb4CTxuq/wQ==,uA+gfRlXLDwWbv3WZzUKAg==,i4rMN0UUVPtygZWmV2BjAw==
API_TOKEN_SALT=TKdLs2Zz5kHcBZm+ezUGrg==
ADMIN_JWT_SECRET=0sGOyBoYX4yY/I7h0ZjXUw==
TRANSFER_TOKEN_SALT=3svjLqZJfpPv2m7rGktZEw==
# Database
DATABASE_CLIENT=sqlite
DATABASE_FILENAME=tmp/data.db
JWT_SECRET=CJsBIoeH11S4/S5tGPTkkg==
```

I am using in my repository this folder **tmp/data.db**

[image]

Comment: Estas en StackOverflow en Español.